# Swift calculate value of UITextFields and return value

Tags: ios, variables, swift, uitextfield, xcode6

Using swift and Xcode 6, I'm trying to return a value calculated based on content of few UITextFields.

I have declared variables

```
var Number1 = Field1.text.toInt()
var Number2 = Field2.text.toInt() 

var Duration = Number1*Number2

Mylabel.text = String ("\(Duration)")
```

The idea is to capture duration from few UI Fields and based on calculation of those values assign that to a variable as well as display it on a label.

In line:  var Duration = Number1*Number2

Challenge is that I have is that when performing multiplication Xcode highlight error: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Variables can't have spaces in them. This: `Number1`, `Number2`. **Not this**: `Number 1`, `Number 2`.

Comment: What problem are you running into? From what code we can see, it should be working properly (other than the spaces that are in the variable names).

Comment: In line:  var Duration = Number1*Number2

Challenge is that I have is that when performing multiplication Xcode highlight error: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: See my answer below.  I tell you how to deal with the optional values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toInt()` method returns an *optional* value because the string it is trying to convert may not contain a proper value.  For instance, these strings will be converted to `nil`: `"house"`, `"3.7"`,`""` (empty string).

Because the values may be `nil`, `toInt()` returns an optional `Int` which is the type `Int?`.  You can't use that value without unwrapping it first.  That is why you are getting the error message.  Here are two safe ways to handle this:

You need to decide what you want to do when a value can't be converted.  If you just want to use `0` in that case, then use the *nil coalescing operator* (`??`) like so:

```
let number1 = field1.text.toInt() ?? 0
// number1 now has the unwrapped Int from field1 or 0 if it couldn't be converted

let number2 = field2.text.toInt() ?? 0
// number2 now has the unwrapped Int from field2 or 0 if it couldn't be converted

let duration = number1 * number2

mylabel.text = "\(duration)"
```

If you want your program to do nothing unless both fields have valid values:

```
if let number1 = field1.text.toInt() {
    // if we get here, number1 contains the valid unwrapped Int from field1

    if let number2 = field2.text.toInt() {
        // if we get here, number2 contains the valid unwrapped Int from field2

        let duration = number1 * number2
        mylabel.text = "\(duration)"
    }
}
```

So, what did the error message mean when it said did you mean to use a `!`.  You can unwrap an optional value by adding a `!` to the end, but **you must be absolutely sure the value is not nil first or your app will crash**.  So you could also do it this way:

```
if number1 != nil && number2 != nil {
    let duration = number1! * number2!
    mylabel.text = "\(duration)"
}
```

Comment: In line:  var Duration = Number1*Number2

Challenge is that I have is that when performing multiplication Xcode highlight error: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much it works. Declaring Variable using : let number1 = field1.text.toInt() ?? 0  worked!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of textFields in var, multiply them, and then set the value of label. Try this:

```
var Number1 = Field1.text.toInt()
var Number2 = Field2.text.toInt() 

var Duration = Number1 * Number2

Mylabel.text = NSString(format:"%d",Duration!)as String;
```

Hope this helps.. :)